# How to set a variable to a string saved with NSUserDefaults. IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

So recently I have been trying to make a simple practice app that saves strings and shows the last one you saved unless you save a new one.  When you open the app it should have the second label set to the last string you saved. The problem I am facing right now is the second label that is supposed to show the last string you saved isnt showing saved value label.

Here is the source code I wrote this all in swift ask me if you have any questions on a road trip hotspot is OP:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Savedlbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Textfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!


    var current = ""
    var Saved = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let currentDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        Savedlbl.text = NSString(format: "", Saved) as String
        if(currentDefault.valueForKey("Saved") != nil) {
           Saved = currentDefault.valueForKey("Saved") as! NSString! as String
           Savedlbl.text = NSString(format: "", Saved) as String
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func Set(sender: AnyObject) {
        setall() 
    } 


    func setall() {
        current = Textfield.text!
        Label.text = Textfield.text!
        var currentDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        Saved = (currentDefault.valueForKey("saved") as? String)!
        currentDefault.setValue(Saved, forKey: "saved")
        Savedlbl.text = Textfield.text  
        currentDefault.synchronize()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func noth() {
        if Saved.isEmpty
        {
            let currentDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


            if(currentDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") != nil)
            {
              Saved = currentDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSString! as String
               Savedlbl.text = NSString(format: "", Saved) as String
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing any format when set label text. Since you pass saved value which you cast as string, your code for set label text should be like this.

```
Savedlbl.text = NSString(format: "%@", Saved)
```

Additionally, i don't see any code to save `Saved` value in your `NSUserDefaults` so you may want to check the value before set the label.